# Does Mango Query on Apache CouchDB v2.3.1 support the \D character in regex selectors

Tags: regex, couchdb

I am trying to run a mango query on CouchDB v2.3.1 with a selector as below...

```
{
   "selector": {
      "title": {
         "$regex": "(?i).*someStuff.*OtherStuff\D*2.*"
      },
   },
}
```

but keep getting the error, "There was an error fetching the query plan". When I remove the \D character from the regex string the query runs fine so I am assuming it is not happy with the \D character. The CouchDB documentation [(https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html)](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html), however, seems to indicate that the regex operator supports the PCRE library of which \D is a part. Any pointers as why this is not working would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried double escaping: `\\D`?

Comment: Yes I have and still get the same error message.

Answer (score -2):

From [the official documentation](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html), we see that the `$regex` operator is described as:

> A regular expression pattern to match against the document field. Only matches when the field is a string value and matches the supplied regular expression. The matching algorithms are based on the Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE) library. For more information about what is implemented, see the see the [Erlang Regular Expression](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html)

By following that link, we see that Erlang Regular Expressions support:

> ### Generic Character Types
>
> Another use of backslash is for specifying generic character types:
>
> **\d**
>      Any decimal digit
>   **\D**
>      Any character that is not a decimal digit

Among others...